# How to manually write the form in template when using forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I try to manually write the form design in the template because what i get from ***{{ form.as_p }}*** looks like shit.

I got a model the refrence the user and another model. Like a connection model for making many to one, with one extra field.

So this is my models, except excluding user model.

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey('group.Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the Group model

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The Forms.py looks like this

```
class UserGroups(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = ('nickname', 'group')
```

Also the view ofc:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserGroup(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserGroups
    template_name = 'users/user_group.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form_class})
```

Now when I use the {{ form.as_p }} in the template. It gets really ugly. The worst part is that since the Group is several. It creates a Select-Option dropdown list.
I don't what this. I want to loop through all Groups and have a nickname input for each. So the user can decide which Group they want to add a nickname to.

This is as far as I get for ding this. It loops through.

```
{% for f in form.group %}
     <label>{{ f }}</label>
     <input id="{{ f.group }}" name="{{ f.group }}" value="{{ f.group|default_if_none:'' }}" type="text" placeholder="nickname" />
{% endfor %}
```

I really don't get how to call pk, field names etc from the form. I cant find any good documentation about this.

Any suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use it using form fields name

```
<form action='' method=''>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.name}}
   {{form.location}}
   {{form.active}}
   <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

you can reefer this doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: It's not the Group model I'm using. It's the UserGroup. I want to get away from the autogenerated Select Option for Groups.